# Two way data binding to a control under a property

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a custom class in which I've implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` and I can happily bind this to the `.Text` property of a TextBox on a form and have the data flow both ways.

I'm now trying to achieve the same thing with a textbox on a usercontrol, via a property:

```
public string MyProperty
{
    get { return MyPropertyTextBox.Text; }
    set { MyPropertyTextBox.Text = value; }
}
```

I can bind my class to the `MyProperty` on the Usercontrol so that the value is set.

But how do I get it so that when I edit the textbox the change is fed back to my class?

**Edit:**

Not sure I explained myself very well + it's WinForms, not WPF.

The text box itself isn't bound, I wanted the 'TextChanged' event of the textbox to also trigger 'PropertyChanged' of the usercontrol property. Built myself a proof of concept test, got that working, and then managed to implement it in my project.

thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: ASP.NET, Windows forms

Answer (score 3):

Add the `OnPropertyChanged` method to your property.  Something like this:

```
private string _myPropertyText;
public string MyProperty
{       
    get { return _myPropertyText; }
    set { 
         if(_myPropertyText != value) 
         {
            _myPropertyText = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("MyPropertyTextBox");
         }
        }
}
```

You didn't mention XAML in your question, but as @RetailCoder has noted, your XAML needs to be set properly as well, like in Alan's answer.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding myProperty,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Comment: +1 but this has to be in conjunction with Alan's answer if the changes need to be propagated *as the text is being edited*. Otherwise I believe the change only actually occurs when the textbox loses focus.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to update while editing, use this xaml

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding myproperty,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Comment: +1 but this has to be in conjunction with actually doing something with the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation, as paqogomez's answer mentions.

Answer (score -2):

while you are directly ready from textbox.Text , any change will be directly detected no need for extra code